# What will the browser load faster a 1000px x 1px image, or 1px by 1000px image

Tags: image, browser, rendering, pagespeed

It seems that since the image is just a chunk of data that it will be the same, but I'm not conclusive on this because I'm not sure how the browser actually renders the image.

Also, what image format for an image of a single color will load the fastest?

Comment: **Don't worry about it**.

Comment: If you're down to timing things at this level, you should probably NOT be working in a browser environment...

Comment: What if the page that is loading is loading a large amount of these 1000px by 1px, so a small difference will add up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Also, what image format for an image of a single color will load the fastest?

If you're going to load a single color, chances are that using an element with `background: #HEX;` will be somewhat faster, as you won't be in need of loading the actual image.

Edit#1:

I created two black jpg-images, 1000x1 and 1x1000 - both ended up the same size (399 bytes).

Further on, I created a 1000x1 png-image, as well as a 1000x1 gif-image (both filled with black) - turns out the sizes were as following:

```
PNG-image: 96 bytes
GIF-image: 63 bytes
```

Winner: The GIF-image, with 33 bytes less data than the PNG-image. If you load 1000 images like the ones used in the test, the overhead using the PNG-format will amount to `33 000 bytes` (or `32.22 kilobytes` if you prefer that format).

Comment: Fair enough, but that wasn't what I was asking. From what I've read gif and png are best suited for solid colors. Would there be any difference between them?

Comment: I updated my post with further information, hopefully it clears a few things up!